# Проверка типа файла PHP

Tags: типы, файлы, php

Код почемуто не корректно опредиляет тиф файла. Делаю масовою загрузку картинок, если файлы небольшого размера (100-200 кб), все рабботает нормально, но если размер файла больше (1-3 мб) начинаются проблемы....

```
  foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v)
  {
  ////// тут разный код ////
  ................

  //////////// проверка типа///////
  if($_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/gif" || $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/png" ||
    $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/jpeg")
    {
    ////////////загружаю изображение    
    .................................
    ////////////загружаю изображение
   }else
      echo "<center><br>Можно загружать только изображения в форматах jpg, jpeg, gif и png.</center>";

  }
```

маленькие картинки грузит на ура,  большые.... загружает только первий файл, а дальше вивводит что сообщение что Можно загружать только изображения в форматах jpg, jpeg, gif и png.

может кто знает из за чего могут быть такие глюки?

Comment: Не по теме, но красивее проверка выглядела бы так:

    $allowedTypes = array('image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg');
    if (in_array($_FILES['file']['type'][$k], $allowedTypes)) { // загружаете

А по теме - сделайте дамп ``$_FILES['file']['type'][$k]`` на каждой итерации и посмотрите, что выходит.

Comment: поствил вывод echo $_FILES['file']['type'][$k].'<br>'; перед проверкой, вот что на экране:

image/jpeg
Можно загружать только изображения в форматах jpg, jpeg, gif и png.
Можно загружать только изображения в форматах jpg, jpeg, gif и png.

загружал три файла....

Comment: может проблема в upload_max_filesize